# File database in java with concurrent (multi-process) access

Tags: java, json, database, orm, rdbms

Is there any FILE-DB library that can be safely queried and updated by multiple java processes (not multiple threads).

It seems that [MapDB](https://www.google.com/search?q=mapdb&oq=mapdb&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.1330j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) and [JSON](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjson.org%2Fjava%2F&ei=i6_1U9rBPMev7Aa1woG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNG2TazupBw9xkDKgkonFe4HYaKkwQ&sig2=x1Ev-_o8JO25O4oppWj2CA) do not support modifying access from multiple processes.

Optionally, I prefer a solution with [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) support.

Thanks.

Comment: I think SQLite does this, NHibernate supports it, so theres your ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

You can use [Server](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) mode to allow multiple java process to access the database file without having file locking issues.

Database URL will look something like

`jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/Users/SomeName/Desktop/h2/SomeDATABASEFile`

Hibernate [officially supports h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_hibernate)

Comment: It seems that h2 requires installing and running its standalone DBMS engine. However, I want to run the DBMS inside my program (as a library).

Comment: No, just include the h2 jar in the classpath. However, in server mode, you need to start the server in a separate java process. You only need h2 jar to start the server, no installation of external standalone program.